# How to strip / replace something from a URL?

Tags: javascript

I have this URL
http://192.168.22.124:3000/temp/box/c939c38adcf1873299837894214a35eb
I want to replace the last part of my URL which is **c939c38adcf1873299837894214a35eb** with something else.
How can I do it?

Comment: You can split your url, then replace last element and join again

Comment: Are you using react-router, if so how is your config and in which file do you want to do this

Comment: var url = result.successful[0].uploadURL;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/temp/box/c939c38adcf1873299837894214a35eb';
somethingelse = 'newhash';
var newUrl = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + somethingelse;
```

Note, using the built-in `substr` and `lastIndexOf` is far quicker and uses less memory than splitting out the component parts to an Array or using a regular expression.

Comment: This is the only readable, short and efficient way to do it imo. It's better than my answer I guess :)

Comment: I prefer memory efficient way of doing things. 
I do like Tim Biegeleisen and Ankit Agarwal answers as well. 
Thank you all =)

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this steps:

1. split the URL with `/`
2. replace the last item of array
3. join the result array using `/`

```js
var url = 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/temp/box/c939c38adcf1873299837894214a35eb';
var res = url.split('/');
res[res.length-1] = 'someValue';
res = res.join('/');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @TedKhi you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace` we can try:

```js
var url = "http://192.168.22.124:3000/temp/box/c939c38adcf1873299837894214a35eb";
var replacement = 'blah';
url = url.replace(/(http.*\/).*/, "$1" + replacement);
console.log(url);
```

We capture everything up to and including the final path separator, then replace with that captured fragment and the new replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Complete guide:

```js
// url
var urlAsString = window.location.href;

// split into route parts
var urlAsPathArray = urlAsString.split("/");

// create a new value
var newValue = "routeValue";

// EITHER update the last parameter
urlAsPathArray[urlAsPathArray.length - 1] = newValue;

// OR replace the last parameter
urlAsPathArray.pop();
urlAsPathArray.push(newValue);

// join the array with the slashes
var newUrl = urlAsPathArray.join("/");

// log
console.log(newUrl);

// output
// http://192.168.22.124:3000/temp/box/routeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
let newUrl = /^.*\//.exec(origUrl)[0] + 'new_ending';
```